# Why does Keras model.summary() not work for my model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have written the following Keras §model:

```
input = Input(shape=(train.shape[1:]))


x = layers.Conv1D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=1)(input)
x = layers.Conv1D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=1)(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=1)(x)
x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)



x = layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)


predictions = layers.Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[protein_input], outputs=[predictions])
plot_model(model,"model.png", show_dtype=True, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

model.summary()
```

Which produces this table:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 1,086,593
Trainable params: 1,086,593
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

`plot_model()` also does not produce a diagram.

The model compiles, and I can run `model.fit`.

```
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer="adam", metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

epochs=100

history = model.fit(x=[train],y=log_training_Kd_labels,
                                validation_data=([val],log_validation_Kd_labels),
                                epochs=epochs,
                                batch_size=100)
```

But I am not sure if any learning is occurring. Can anyone advise why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably mixing keras and tensorflow libraries. Since Tensorflow implemented keras libraries, this a common mistake between developers that import keras and tensorflow and use both of them randomly and this leads to some weird behavior.

**Just use either `import tensorflow.keras` or `import keras` in your entire code.**

For example if I code like this (use both library randomly):

```
import keras                                #import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense   #import layers from tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras import Input

input = Input(shape = (20,))
x = Dense(30, name = 'dense1')(input)
x = Dense(20, name = 'dense2')(x)
output = Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = input ,outputs = output)
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam')
model.summary()
```

The output will be:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 1,271
Trainable params: 1,271
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

But if I modify imports and use just `tensorflow.keras` and not use `keras` like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

input = Input(shape = (20,))
x = Dense(30, name = 'dense1')(input)
x = Dense(20, name = 'dense2')(x)
output = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inputs = input ,outputs = output)
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam')
model.summary()
```

I will get the output like this:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 20)]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense1 (Dense)               (None, 30)                630       
_________________________________________________________________
dense2 (Dense)               (None, 20)                620       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 21        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,271
Trainable params: 1,271
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```